# Linear differential equation with fundamental solutions $\sin x$ and $e^x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How could I just make a differential equation out of the blue that has the fundamental solutions $y=c_1\sin x$ and $y=c_2e^x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't make a linear equation with constant real coefficients, because for real polynomials the complex roots come in conjugate pairs. So I would need a 3rd order problem to get those two to be solutions (and in that case $\cos(x)$ would be the other solution). For instance I can note $(x^2+1)(x-1)=x^3-x^2+x-1$ and then use

$$y'''-y''+y'-y=0.$$

A second order equation with those two fundamental solutions would be significantly more complicated than this. The naive idea I had was to use $(x-1)(x-i)=x^2-(i+1)x+i$ and then consider

$$y''-(i+1)y'+iy=0$$

but you can check that this doesn't actually work for $\sin(x)$, since only $e^{ix}$ and not also $e^{-ix}$ is a solution to this equation.

Comment: @EricJohnson ? ${}$

Comment: then how do i make it work for sinx?

Comment: The first one already does. The second one was there to show that such an equation cannot be a second order linear equation with constant coefficients, even if the coefficients are allowed to be complex. There might still be an appropriate linear equation out there, but it can't have constant coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

an alternative to the fine answer by Ian.
the fundamental solutions must satisfy the linearity property of solutions to linear odes as follows.
$$
y = c_1 \sin x + c_2 \mathrm{e}^x\\
y' = c_1 \cos x + c_2\mathrm{e}^x\\
y'' = -c_1\sin x + c_2 \mathrm{e}^x.
$$
so we can "remove" $c_1\sin x$ by combining $y''$ and $y'$
$$
y'' + y' = 2c_2 \mathrm{e}^x
$$
we can not remove $c_2\mathrm{e}^x$ with just the above since we will just introduce $c_1\sin x$ back into the ode..so we go one step further
$$
y''' = -c_1\cos x + c_2\mathrm{e}^x.
$$
now we can get an expression for $c_2 \mathrm{e}^x$ by doing a similar process
$$
y''' + y' = 2c_2 \mathrm{e}^x
$$
subtract the two resulting equations to yeild
$$
y''' + y' - y'' -y =  \\
y''' -y'' + y' - y = 0
$$